# submit a form with jQuery after delay

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a very simple form in HTML and I'd like to submit this form after 2000ms (of delay) from when the document is ready, without push the submit button.
How can I do this with a jQuery script?

```
<form id="my_form" action="NextPage.php" method="post">
    <fieldset class="my_fieldset">
        <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="value_A" checked="checked"/>Value A<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="value_B"/>Value B<br/>
    </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="Send"  tabindex="110">
</form>
```

I can't find a command to say "when ... submit the form".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to wait with [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function and then [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) the form itself:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_form').delay(2000).submit();
});
```

Comment: $(this).delay(2000).html('Sending'); is that correct,

Comment: Changing of the state of the element will happen immediately and `delay()` wouldn't work in your case. https://jsfiddle.net/26nac0kj/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('#my_form').submit();
  }, 2000);
});
```