# How to set a time limit on something for PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a quiz and am trying to do a time limit but cannot find the right syntax so I am asking if anyone can help me.

For example: 2min to finish a test then after 2 min test ends.

Comment: It would help if you could post some code or further explain in more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve... you could use the function `time()` to store the time of start of the test... and then once the test has finished you could use `time()` again and subtract it from the start time, getting the number of seconds it took them to complete. Having said that you might actually be looking forward to have a client-side (JavaScript) solution as well...

Comment: Most likely you want to have something like a countdown indicating the time someone has left to answer a question or similar. That would be something that has to be implemented on the client side, so in javascript. It has nothing to do with php, since php is only used for operations on the server side.

Comment: There are several ways to do a timer. But as always, it depends on what you want to do. If your quiz is just for fun, it might be enough to do the timer in javascript on the client side. If it should be tamper proof, you need to do it on the server side (never trust client side code). What is your requirement?

Comment: the solution would not be exclusively client side if you want it to be robust... The client can easily be hacked... the server cannot... so I would suggest implementing both the client and the server side code... The client is just an indicator (count down timer), and the server has the actual validation... that's how I would do it

Comment: I'm thinking you want to auto submit a form after some delay. This could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947515/submit-a-form-with-jquery-after-delay

Comment: it wont automatially calculate unless you are using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with help of javascript or jquery along with php. On page load, you can initiate countdown timer and a user can play or have access to the game until counter reach to zero. Once the counter reaches to zero, you can show a message like Time over or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume you have two PHP pages, the first (quiz.php) is the test one and the second one is where the form of the test is sent to (submit.php).

you can achieve this with simple use of php sessions.

so in quiz.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['startTime'] = time(); //saves the current time

// display the quiz and do everything else
```

and then in submit.php

```
session_start();
$submitTime = time(); // get the time at moment of submit
$startTime = $_SESSION['startTime']; // retrieve the saved variable
$quizTime = $submitTime - $startTime;
if ($quizTime > $myLimit) { //time difference in seconds...
    // the quiz is rejected
} else {
    // the quiz is aproved
}
```

as other answer o comments may suggest you can also validate this with JavaScript, but I recommend you to do this in both places as anything in the user side can be altered and thus is not secure.

ref links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php php sessions
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php time function

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you use javascript for that. you can easily do it with javascript. hens you want to do it on client site it will be more efficient too.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // Your code here
}, 20000);
```